# using singleton objects

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, singleton

I'm trying to make a card game deck builder.

I have made several scenes with JavaFX and established data classes (`Deck`, `Card`, and `Character` class). By making the Deck class Singleton in each of the scene controllers I have access to the same Deck object.

At the same time, I need just one more object of `Deck` where I can keep all cards in. I made a class, `AllCardsDeck`, by extending the `Deck` class. With this method, can i make an object of `AllCardsDeck` and keep regular players deck separate?

Also, when I make an object of `AllCardsDeck`, does it affect the parent class with singleton pattern, `Deck`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern ; also, how is this related to JavaFX at all?

Comment: This just looks like a really good example of why you shouldn't use the Singleton pattern solely for the purpose of making it easy to access an object. Use the Singleton pattern when it inherently makes sense to only ever create a single instance.

Comment: are you sure you need a brand new class for `Deck` at all? Have you considered just using a `List` or  `Set`?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that you need two different classes; a deck is a deck. You should have a `Deck` class with two instances : `currentDesk` and `allCards`.

So you just have to construct a class that is instantiated only two times (not a singleton - a doubleton?). The principles are exactly the same, there is no need to apply patterns exactly, especially for Singleton, just to respect the idea.

Comment: there are a few things that are different about the two decks, such as max number of cards allowed for a deck, and character class for a deck. All cards deck ignore maxnum and hero class so that's why i made it by extending it. To think of it now, It would have been a better idea to make allCardsDeck and then extend that to make regular Deck class. Thank you for your comment. It helped!

Answer (score 1):

As its name and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern) state, Singleton Pattern means that you will only create **one instance** of the Deck object. If you create two or more instances then it won't be a Singleton.

In this problem you need **one Deck** for allowing players to draw cards and something like a **Hand class** that instanciates for every player, as it is the place where each of them keep their owncards.

This way you will have your Deck singleton working (as in there is only one maze in a game) and a Hand for each player. They are separate things and should be treated as that.